# DrawerItems not showing from StackNavigator (react-navigation)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Currently Im trying to make a drawer using react-navigation. 
my react-navigation version is : "^1.0.0-beta.7"

Basically my structure of react-navigation look like this

StackNavigator as the root..
DrawerNavigator as the 2nd layer..
and another StackNavigator as the 3rd layer..

My problem is that when I put my component inside DrawerNavigator, The Component header will not show up after navigate to the component.. So, Im hoping anyone who can pointed to me how to make header visible when I put my component inside DrawerNavigator. If I did not put any component inside DrawerNavigator and all the screen inside the inner StackNavigator, the header will be visible but then the DrawerItems doesnt have any props thus not showing inside the drawer.

```js
const rootNav = StackNavigator({
  MainDrawerNavigator: { screen: MainDrawerNavigator }
}, {
  headerMode: 'screen',
  navigationOptions: { header: null }
})

const MainDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeNavigator },
  Logout: { screen: Logout }
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  drawerWidth: 270,
  headerMode: 'screen',
  contentComponent: (props) => {
      return(
        <ScrollView>
          <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </ScrollView>
      )
  },
  contentOptions: {
    style: {
      marginTop: 0,
    }
  }
})

const HomeNavigator = StackNavigator({
    HomeMenu: { screen: HomeMenu },
    StartJourney: { screen : StartJourney },
    JournalList: { screen: JournalList },
)}
```

[image]

Hope anyone can help me with this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to achieve where DrawerOpen the header will not show

I don' understand which header here is?

> but when I navigate the route from Drawer and it open a screen, then
>   the header will show up

If you're talking about navigator header, it's header of `HomeNavigator`, you can do like you did with rootNav `navigationOptions: { header: null }`

```
 const HomeNavigator = StackNavigator({
    HomeMenu: { screen: HomeMenu },
    StartJourney: { screen : StartJourney },
    JournalList: { screen: JournalList },
},{
navigationOptions: { header: null }
})
```

And current react-navigation document is for `beta.9 / beta.10` I don't know if these props work on `beta.7`. There are some big changes on style and props from beta.7 to beta.8

Comment: sorry.. I think before this my question make people confused and it quite hard to convert to proper english.. I already edited my question and I hope it 's much clear :-) 

Tq anyway for responding and give head up, I just noticed it's already beta 10!